# Stephen Abbott "Understanding Analysis": is my proof correct?

Tags: analysis

I am self studying Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* and I just want to ask if my proof on exercise 1.3.4 is correct. The question is:

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, bounded above, and they satisfy $B\subseteq A$. Show that $sup\ B \leq sup\ A$.

My proof uses *lemma 1.3.7* in the book which says:

Assume $s\in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then, $s=sup\ A$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an element $a\in A$ satisfying $s-\epsilon <a$.

In my proof then, since $B$ is bounded above, then by the axiom of completeness $sup\ B$ also exists, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $b\in B$ such that
$$sup\ B-\epsilon<b.$$

Then suppose for contradiction that $sup\ B> sup\ A$, which implies $sup\ B-sup\ A>0$, then pick $\epsilon := sup\ B-sup\ A$ so that:
$$ sup\ B -(sup\ B - sup\ A)<b$$
$$\implies sup\ A <b, $$
which finally is a contradiction since every element of $b$ is in $A$, and there should not be an element of $A$ greater than $sup\ A$. Therefore $sup\ B \leq sup\ A$. I know there's a way to prove this directly but my proof by contradiction method just came more naturally to me, I am not sure if it is correct though.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The more direct way you're referencing is something along the lines of: since $B\subset A$, every upper bound of $A$ is also an upper bound of $B$. In particular, $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $B$ and hence $\sup B≤ \sup A$.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have the solutions manual with me, and I was presented with that solution after I checked if I did the same method. Having a solutions manual with me is very helpful for self-studying, but I only get one perspective.

Comment: Knowing different proofs for the same thing is always useful. You might also find that, over time, what you find more natural changes, especially when most sources seem to favor one particular method, for whatever reasons.

Comment: Could you share a solution manual, please?

Comment: @Max can you share solution manual?